# CSS Changes Not Showing In HTML site

Tags: css, styles, sftp, stylesheet, ftp-client

My CSS changes are not showing once I upload to FTP.  HTML changes show just fine.  This is the web page in question:-

[Activ Physiotherapy](http://www.activphysiotherapy.co.uk/activ-run-fit.html)

Hosted with 1and1 and recently had an SSL certificate installed.  I think it is an APACHE SERVER.

I have tried caching, deleting history and cookies and no luck with that.  I deleted css file from root and the website still had all the css styled correctly as if the css file was still in the root.

I think something is wrong with my FTP but I do not know what to be able to fix it.  It is like it is getting uploaded to the wrong webspace.

I should also mention that the changes work just fine locally in all browsers, just nothing when uploaded via FTP.

Comment: Can't you ask for help from you hosting provider? I don't think that here is the place to ask question like this due StackOverflow is code related community.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I know I apologise for this.  I have asked them and they are no help unfortunately.  i was grabbing at straws that maybe someone here may have had some experience with this.

Comment: @Ruin, I gone through your CSS file located at http://www.activphysiotherapy.co.uk/styles/activphysiotherapy.css. I could see you have copy/pasted the whole CSS styles twice within the stylesheet(activphysiotherapy.css). Can you check and remove the dulpication ?

Comment: Thanks for looking. This gets stranger as the file I have has no duplicated code.

Comment: I just wanted to offer an update in case anyone goes through the same thing.  It is a caching issue however the hard refresh and clearing cookies etc was useless for me.  Therefore in the end I added a string to the html tag in the <head>.  Like so:-     <link href="styles/activphysiotherapy.css?v1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to offer an update in case anyone goes through the same thing. It is a caching issue however the hard refresh and clearing cookies etc was useless for me.

Therefore in the end I added a string to the html tag in the . Like so:-

"styles/activphysiotherapy.css?v1"

This has forced the cache immediately.